# How to set HTTP Request Header "authentication" using HTTPClient?

Tags: java, authorization, httpclient, basic-authentication

I want to set the HTTP Request header "Authorization" when sending a POST request to a server.
How do I do it in Java? Does HttpClient have any support for it?

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRQ_Headers.html#z9

The server requires me to set some specific value for the authorization field:
of the form ID:signature which they will then use to authenticate the request.

Thanks
Ajay

Answer (score 5):

Below is the example for setting request headers

```
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("someurl");

    post.addHeader(key1, value1));
    post.addHeader(key2, value2));
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code for a [Basic Access Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication):

```
HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://example.com/auth");
request.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic ThisIsJustAnExample");
```

And then just an example of how to execute it:

```
HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(httpParams, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 3000);
HttpClient httpclient = null;
httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);

Log.d("Log------------", "Status Code: " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is "answered" here:
[Http Basic Authentication in Java using HttpClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283234/http-basic-authentication-in-java-using-httpclient)

There are many ways to do this.  It was frustrating for me to try to find the answer.  I found that the best was the Apache docs for HttpClient.
Note: answers will change over time as the libraries used will have deprecated methods.
http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/tutorial/html/authentication.html