# Tomcat manager connection through HttpClient

Tags: java, tomcat, basic-authentication

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong here?  I added the username and password to the tomcat-user.xml but I am still getting a "401 Unauthorized" error.

```
String url = "http://localhost:9080/manager/list";
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
httppost.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + userPass);

log.debug("executing request {}", httppost.getRequestLine());
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent()));
String line;
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
buffer.append(line);
buffer.append('\n');
}
rd.close();
```

Comment: What version of tomcat are you using? The urls and required roles for the manager app changed between tomcat 6 and tomcat 7.

Comment: For this I am using apache-tomcat-5.5.33

Comment: What role are you giving your user in tomcat-user.xml?

Comment: Another possibility is that you may not be performing the Basic Auth step correctly. I've updated my answer with a helpful link.

Comment: here is the entry in my tomcat-user.xml <user username="user" password="pass" roles="admin,manager"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on whether you're using Tomcat 5.5/6 or Tomcat 7.

### Tomcat 7

You'll need to access the the listing with the following URL:

```
http://localhost:9080/manager/text/list
```

- http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#List_Currently_Deployed_Applications

You'll need to configure tomcat-user.xml with a user that has the `manager-script` role.

- http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Configuring_Manager_Application_Access

### Tomcat 5.5/6

You'll need to access the the listing with the following URL:

```
http://localhost:9080/manager/list
```

- http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/manager-howto.html#List_Currently_Deployed_Applications (Tomcat 5.5 docs referenced because for some reason the Tomcat 6 docs contain the Tomcat 7 specific instructions)

You'll need to configure tomcat-user.xml with a user that has the `manager` role.

- http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/manager-howto.html#Configuring_Manager_Application_Access

### Update

You may not be performing the Basic Auth step correctly. The username/pass might need to be base64 encoded. See the highest voted answer in this question: [Http Basic Authentication in Java using HttpClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283234/http-basic-authentication-in-java-using-httpclient)

Comment: here is the entry in my tomcat-user.xml <user username="user" password="pass" roles="admin,manager"/>  I had already added this entry prior to testing and still received the above mentioned error.

Comment: @peekay The next thing to look at is how you're doing the Basic Auth using `HttpPost`. I think the username/pass must be base64 encoded. See the highest voted answer in the question I linked to at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: well I have a different error now so I guess that's progress :) now I am getting a "400 Bad Request" so I guess that means it was the encoding.  Thanks

Comment: @peekay: Make sure you use the format `user:pass` for the string that you base64 encode.

Comment: @peekay Also, you should probably be using `HTTP GET` for this operation instead of `HTTP POST`.

Comment: So as it turns out the 400 Bad request was due to the Base64 encoder adding a '\n' to the end of the end of the final string value.  I removed the '\n' and resubmitted and the world was filled with hugs and puppy dogs.  thanks everyone for all your help.

Comment: @peekay Thanks for the update. I was wondering how you finally resolved this.

Comment: the first problem was because I forgot to add basic auth to the request. I was doing the base64 encryption but never added it to the request.  the second problem (400 bad request) was due to a '\n' at the end of the base64 encoded string.  for what ever reason the base64 encoder was adding the \n to the end of the sting that then caused the request to crash and burn.