# Axis2 working with even BASIC authentication

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

Is it even possible? The documentation does not make it clear. I've tried all sorts of different mechanisms to get authentication working, but I continually get a "401: Unauthorized" error. Here is where I am at:

```
    stub = new EngineStub();

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.getParams().setAuthenticationPreemptive(true);
    stub._getServiceClient().getServiceContext().getConfigurationContext().setProperty(HTTPConstants.CACHED_HTTP_CLIENT, client);

    HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator auth = new HttpTransportProperties.Authenticator();
    List<String> authpref = new ArrayList<String>();
    authpref.add(AuthPolicy.BASIC);
    auth.setAuthSchemes(authpref);
    auth.setUsername(username); 
    auth.setPassword(password);
    auth.setPreemptiveAuthentication(true);
    stub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(HTTPConstants.AUTHENTICATE, auth);
```

Comment: Have a look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283234/http-basic-authentication-in-java-using-httpclient

Comment: Also share the details how security is configured for these web-services.

Comment: The documentation on this is useless. The whole thing is broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you mean axis2 work with BASIC AUTH? If your backend service is secured using basic auth, all you have to do is set the basic auth header from client and send requests. Your client code looks right;  not sure about auth policy;try without like this;

```
 auth.setUsername(USER_NAME);
    auth.setPassword(PASSWORD);
    auth.setPreemptiveAuthentication(true);
    option.setProperty(org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.AUTHENTICATE, auth);
    option.setManageSession(true);
```

Comment: Answered a few years later, but answered none the less.  (And edited a few years later again.)