# Same connection to get information by DOM and execute POST.

Tags: java, android, http, post

I should get information from a website by DOM (a random value of an hidden input) and execute a post of username and password in my app (a login).

If I use two separated connection the random value change and not log me in.
Someone knows how I can do this in one connection? Help me please!

Answer (score 0):

You should provide your login information in headers, there is a standard way of doing so called HTTP BASIC authentication. Read more about it here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication

You can follow this SO post to understand how you can send an http request with BAISC authentication header using JAVA:

[Http Basic Authentication in Java using HttpClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283234/http-basic-authentication-in-java-using-httpclient)

Your request can be authenticated using the mentioned header. And you can send any other information as request parameter. Using this way you need not to send two requests to get the DOM info as your authentication info will be in header.

Comment: Can you post an example with the DOM before the post? thanx