# How to login to an HTTPS web server using android?

Tags: java, android, https, webserver

i'm trying to create an android app to admin my university resources (exams, etc..) but i realized that there is not a simple login, like most of the other websites (one textbox for the username, one textbox for the password, one button to submit, on the page). I'm asked to insert username and password through something like a dialogbox.

Here is a screenshot I took to show you what is about [image]

Now my question is, is there any way I can login to this server, without showing this page?
(I want to ask the user to submit username and password via an activity, and login to the webserver underground, saving user and password for future access)

Comment: it's all just http. fire off a post with the appropriate field=value pairs, to the appropriate url, etc...

Comment: that is the problem, i don't know how to find out which is the field name..

Comment: it's a website. do a view source, use the brower's debug tools (e.g. right click one of the input fields, right-click, "inspect element").

Comment: @ParKein It looks like that site uses [basic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) (which is hardly recommended anymore).

Comment: @Biffen so you think that if I do something like this it will work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283234/http-basic-authentication-in-java-using-httpclient

Comment: @ParKein Yeah, it should. Probably.