# How to remotely login to a Jenkins server using Java?

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-cli

I'm trying to login remotely to a Jenkins server using Java.

I didn't found some documentation on how this should be securely done.

For my local server using the url: http://user:pass@server doesn't work .

Can anybody recommend me some documentation regarding this topic ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us the code please, do you use apache HttpClient ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documention from [jenkins wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Authenticating+scripted+clients)

Should work with your Basic Authentication type.

**Java example with httpclient 4.3.x**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;

import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.AuthCache;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.protocol.HttpClientContext;
import org.apache.http.impl.auth.BasicScheme;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicAuthCache;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class JenkinsScraper {

    public String scrape(String urlString, String username, String password) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        URI uri = URI.create(urlString);
        HttpHost host = new HttpHost(uri.getHost(), uri.getPort(), uri.getScheme());
        CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credsProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(uri.getHost(), uri.getPort()), new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password));
        // Create AuthCache instance
        AuthCache authCache = new BasicAuthCache();
        // Generate BASIC scheme object and add it to the local auth cache
        BasicScheme basicAuth = new BasicScheme();
        authCache.put(host, basicAuth);
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider).build();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(uri);
        // Add AuthCache to the execution context
        HttpClientContext localContext = HttpClientContext.create();
        localContext.setAuthCache(authCache);

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(host, httpGet, localContext);

        return EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    }

}
```

Comment: My problem actually concerns with security, is it ok to send  the password directly from user into UsernamePasswordCredentials without crypting ?

Comment: Well if it is more a security question than programming, I would not recommend remote login using http and basic auth. I would prefer some kind of security in front, some vpn or ssh tunnel before reaching the host.

Comment: Sending it over http will allow anyone in your network to catch the password, it is plain text and easy to grab. As said, I would not open my server for public or remote logon. But using a secure Vpn or ssh tunnel or... will make it more secure.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I will investigate on that then !

Answer (score 1):

The Http/Html way is the most cumbersome! I would use jenkins cli or remote api. If you still insist using Java with http then you need to use basic http-authentication and if you plan on trigger more steps inside jenkins use a proper Http/Html Java library like Java-Selenium or HttpUnit.

Best and simple solution for using http basic auth in Java I found here:
[Http Basic Authentication in Java using HttpClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283234/http-basic-authentication-in-java-using-httpclient)

- Also check, if your use case can be covered by jenkins cli:
  https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+CLI

  How to use jenkins cli from the command line:

  java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s yourserver.com help [command]

  > The cli works with username & password and also can handle certificates for https connection.
- Also check the Remote API:
  https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API