# How to use curl in Java

Tags: java, curl

I've found there are several discussions about this topic, but what confuses me is another question. You see, the Object URL is used to get data from certain page. But how to write the URL when the page requires authorities?

The API suggests the curl code `curl -i -X GET --header 'X-Auth-code:<your_code>'` to be used, but how?

Comment: By authorities, I suppose you mean the custom `X-Auth-code` header? If that's so, you can add custom headers to GET request in java. Just google or search on StackOverflow. Btw, just because the API suggest usage of curl, doesn't mean you have to use curl only. You can use standard JDK components / open source libraries to make HTTP requests.

Answer (score 2):

To run command in a Java program, you could use `Process` and `Runtime`.

Try something like bellow:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("curl -i -X ");
InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Could be a problem with quoting.  Or more specifically that `exec` does not understand quoting at all.  The solution is to supply the command name and options as an array of strings ... so that you don't need any quoting.

Comment: @Stone - you need to show use >>exactly<< what you tried.

Comment: @mmuzahid sorry for your waiting, I just found the api gave me a wrong curl command. After correcting it, there only remains the question that I use url to link the Api

Comment: But error showed that MalformedURLException: no protocol. I am running on Windows, is there any chance that the Windows does not support curl?

Comment: @Stone - may be an encode problem you have. Try something like ``java.net.URLEncoder.encode(paramValue, "UTF-8");`` before using it

Comment: Why are  you not updating your question with the code you have tried?

Comment: @mmuzahid you know I am now in mainland China so I can hardly visit stackoverflow site using pc. But I just fixed the problem and can post the code, so please have a look. Many thanks

Comment: On one occasion I tried  String  requestUrl = "curl -X GET --header \"X-Auth-Code: d16e16f5ba658c1118f52666b1469d96\" -i http://121.41.106.89:8010/";      and use   URL url = new URL(requestUrl);

HttpURLConnection httpUrlConn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

Comment: this gives the error: java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: curl -X GET --header "X-Auth-Code: d16e16f5ba658c1118f52666b1469d96" -i http://121.41.106.89:8010/

Comment: I also try to use process, but it has little connection with my intention, that is to get the json type data from the site http://121.41.106.89:8010/

Answer (score 1):

This is the final solution: the key is the `setRequestProperty()` method

```
     try {
        String url = "http://121.41.106.89:8010/";

        URL readUrl = new URL(url);
        URLConnection connection = readUrl.openConnection();
        connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        connection.setRequestProperty("X-Auth-Code", "75d07493b655591137dbc905ede428ce");
        connection.connect();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String result = in.readLine();
        System.out.println(result);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    URL url = new URL("http://stackoverflow.com");

    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new   InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), "UTF-8"))) {
    for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
```

I think [this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586975/how-to-use-curl-in-java) may help you.

Comment: Yep, I know your idea. But what is important is when authority is required. Your suggestion does not solve this problem, I 'm afraid

Comment: you can set the user and password in header of post request. check this Url als : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283234/http-basic-authentication-in-java-using-httpclient. @Stone