# 401 Unauthorized when calling webservice through javacode

Tags: web-services, jersey-2.0, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have to call web service through java. When i hit the web-service URL in browser it asks for user name and password and i can see the result,
But when i am trying to call it using java code i am getting error like

> You are not authorized to view this page  BODY { font: 8pt/12pt verdana }  H1 { font: 13pt/15pt verdana }  H2 { font: 8pt/12pt verdana }  A:link { color: red }  A:visited { color: maroon }
>
> ## You are not authorized to view this page
>
> You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied because your Web browser is sending a WWW-Authenticate header field that the Web server is not configured to accept.
>
> ---
>
> Please try the following:
>
> - Contact the Web site administrator if you believe you should be able to view this directory or page.
> - Click the Refresh button to try again with different credentials.
>
> ### HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to server configuration.
> Internet Information Services (IIS)
>
> ---
>
> Technical Information (for support personnel)
>
> - Go to [Microsoft Product Support Services](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=8180) and perform a title search for the words **HTTP** and **401**.
> - Open **IIS Help**, which is accessible in IIS Manager (inetmgr), and search for topics titled **About Security**, **Authentication**, and **About Custom Error Messages**.
>
> i am not able access the the result using SOAP UI

i am really stuck ,i tried using httpclient/jersey

please help how can i send username and password using java code

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.NTCredentials;
import org.apache.http.auth.params.AuthPNames;
import org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.params.AuthPolicy;
import org.apache.http.client.protocol.ClientContext;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;


public class NTLM_TRY2 {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
          DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://10.0.134.114/eBill/bpsWebService.asmx"); 
            CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
            credsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,
                    new NTCredentials("abc", "acb@578", "", ""));

                java.util.List<String> authtypes = new ArrayList<String>();
                authtypes.add(AuthPolicy.NTLM);
                authtypes.add(AuthPolicy.DIGEST);
                authtypes.add(AuthPolicy.BASIC);
                httpclient.getParams().setParameter(AuthPNames.PROXY_AUTH_PREF,
                        authtypes);
                httpclient.getParams().setParameter(AuthPNames.TARGET_AUTH_PREF,
                        authtypes);

            localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.CREDS_PROVIDER, credsProvider);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget, localContext);
            System.out.println("Response code: " + response.getStatusLine());


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is basic authentication you have to send the user an password in the header of the request.

See this question in SO. 
[Http Basic Authentication in Java using HttpClient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283234/http-basic-authentication-in-java-using-httpclient)